# Need help in generating dynamic result based on the query in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to generate the results dynamically based on the query passed in the front end. 
Here is my code....

```
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4'><tr>";
foreach ($resultant->list_fields() as $field) {
    echo "<th>$field</th>";
}

foreach ($resultant->result_array() as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    $resultants = $this->db->query($query);         
    foreach ($resultants->list_fields() as $newFields) {
        echo "<td>$row[$newFields]</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I got the expected result. I need to keep on initiating the column values using
`$resultants = $this->db->query($query);`

I wonder this will impact on the performance. So please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as it nested loop again it will impact the performance. As I understand, you want all the field names in second query. Here is how you can avoid that. (There are other methods to get the number of fields though).

```
echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4'><tr>";
$fieldcount=0;
foreach ($resultant->list_fields() as $field) {
    echo "<th>$field</th>";
$fieldcount++;
}

foreach ($resultant->result_array() as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<$fieldcount; $i++) {
        echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this loop is used to get the column names and for count.      foreach ($resultants->list_fields() as $newFields) {
        echo "<td>$row[$newFields]</td>";
    }

Comment: You can store the $resultants->list_fields in an array at the top and loop through the array instead of $resultants object.